# how to parse several arguments using command line arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

i am writing a command line utility in which i want to parse several arguments: right now i am not reading data from address(so please don't get confuse by -addr); my primary objective is to design the framework so that i can parse several arguments as follows.

```
filename read -addr value -addr2 value2 -addrN valueN -length value -range value -length2 value2 -lengthN valueN -width value -width2 value2 -widthN valueN
```

the N can have a maximum value of 64 and minimum value of 1.

Please give some valuable suggestions so that i can do it.
Thanks

Comment: Show us your code so far, and explain your difficulties.  Otherwise, this is "send teh codez plz".

Comment: I think we can provide help without doing the actual parsing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider using the Getopt library or some of its modifications, it can make yout life easier.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: can you please tell me what is the equivalent of getopt() under windows.Actually i am using VC++.

Answer (score 1):

The typical `main()` prototype goes like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   // stuff
}
```

When your program is executed from a command-line, `argc` will be the total count of your arguments, plus one for the name of the program itself; and you can think of argv as an array of strings containing the arguments.

Knowing `argc`, parsing the argument list should be easy :)

Edit: a short example, just in case.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%d\n", argc);
}
```

Then, on your cl:

```
./program asd asd asd
4
```

argv[0] is "program", argv[1] is "asd", etc.

Comment: @ Santiago Lezica hey hi i know about command line arguments but i am dealing with variable number of arguments, like i can provide any number of arguments at command line;this is the thing which is causing me the problem. Can any one of you provide help on variable number of arguments i know may be "getopt" can solve my problem but i dont know how to use it.

Comment: As long as you know the total number of arguments, you have no problem iterating through them and deciding which settings they affect. Just loop and analyze.